# Backbone view events not firing when input altered on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Below is a simple model/corresponding view that I've set up. It's linked to a table with a couple drop downs and one input text box. I want the view methods to fire when the values in the text box and drop downs are changed, however I haven't had any luck.

Using the `console.log` statments and breakpoints, the only method that seems to execute is the `initialize` method in the model. None of the view methods fire when the drop down/input box values change.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qneL65zs/14/

**Backbone**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var QuoteHistory = Backbone.Model.extend({
        //urlRoot: '/Values/SaveQuote',

        defaults: {
            hub: new Backbone.SignalR("QuoteHub"),
            avgHist: "",
            State: "",
            AgeGroup: "",
            Purchase: "",
            PastQuote: "",
            Date: "",
            AverageQuote: ""
        },

        initialize: function () {
            console.log("Model initialize");
        }
    });

    var QuoteView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#QuoteInput'),

        events: {
            "input td input#QuotePurchase": "udpatePurchase",
            "change #QuoteAge": "udpateQuoteAge",
            "change #QuoteState": "udpateState",
            "click #QuoteSave": "udpateModel"
        },

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'updatePurchase', 'updateQuoteAge', 'updateState');

            this.model.bind('change', this.updatePurchase);
            this.model.bind('change', this.updateQuoteAge);
            this.model.bind('change', this.updateState);
        },

        render: function () {
            console.log("render");
            this.model.pullAverageQuote();
        },

        updatePurchase: function() {
            console.log("update purchase");
            var val = this.$el.find('#QuotePurchase').val();
            this.model.set({ Purchase: val });
        },

        updateQuoteAge: function () {
            console.log("update age");
            var val = this.$el.find('#QuoteAge option:selected').val();
            this.model.set({ AgeGroup: val });
        },

        updateState: function () {
            console.log("update state");
            var val = this.$el.find('#QuoteState option:selected').val();
            this.model.set({ State: val });
        },

        updateModel: function () {
            console.log("update model");
            this.model.save(this, {
                success: function() {
                    console.log("success");
                    this.model.pullAverageQuote();
                },

                error: function(error) {
                    console.log("error during update");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $(function() {
        var quoteHistory = new QuoteHistory;
        var quoteView = new QuoteView({ model: quoteHistory });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="QuoteInput">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2"></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>State</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="QuoteState">
                                            <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                                            <option value="CA">CA</option>
                                            <option value="OR">OR</option>
                                            <option value="WA">WA</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Age Group</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="QuoteAge">
                                            <option value="35_45">35-45</option>
                                            <option value="45_55">45-55</option>
                                            <option value="55_65">55-65</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Purchase Payment</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" id="QuotePurchase" style="width: 6em; text-align: center;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"><button type="button" id="QuoteSave">Save</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

**EDIT**

Screen shot below is from `console.log(this)` statement in the View's `initialize` method

[image]

**SECOND EDIT**

Below is the output of a `console.log(this)` statement placed at the end of the `initialize` method of the view.

This output is the same as the `console.log(quoteView)` statement mentioned is the comments below.

[image]

Comment: in the initialize event, do console.log(this) - then take a look at the _events property in inspector, what do you see?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see an event property. Screen shot attached

Comment: Thanks, what does the DOM look like, is backbone view adding additional element with the same ID?  This can happen sometimes.  this.el CAN do that.

Comment: Did a ctl+F search after hitting "Inspect Source" and couldn't find more than one instance of each id in the HTML up there.

Comment: ok, just noticed something with your el: declaration. I dont think you are supposed to use a jquery object there. it does that for you with $el.  This might be breaking the event listening.

Comment: you sent the wrong screenshot, please do `console.log(quoteView)`

Comment: instead of console.log(this) at the end of the view initiailize, how about do a `console.log(quoteView)` after you invoke it with `new`

Comment: it loooks like you have model events, but no view events.

Comment: fold the $el property and fold the model property, lets just see the view properties folded :) if you see __events unfold that.

Comment: I have to go now, I hope the issue gets resolved!!

Comment: have to say, am stumped, it looks good!  the events are loaded.  The only thing I can think of is that the quoteView is not being attached to the DOM.  Is it rendering? or just initializing? It might have to do with that being wrapped in an anonymous function.  It might be better to invoke it outside of it, I'm not sure.  I hope you get it resolved.  Wish I could help more :)

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I have another view/model in this project that's set up exactly the same, however it works like a charm. Thanks anyway for the help :)

Comment: I was thinking, I wonder if this view is really attached to the DOM?  It could be that you are rendering the original table but the view $el is not connected to it.  I think it might be good if you try $('body').append(this.$el) or something similar.  Just a thought.  You could also console.log(this.$el[0]), and it should output the dom node, when you click on the node in console, it should highlihgt its location in the DOM. If nothing is highlihgted, then its not attached.

Comment: Should this go in the `initialize` function?

Comment: I think it should go in the render function actually. but then you would want to call the render() function as well.

Comment: Set up this fiddle for the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qneL65zs/14/

Comment: the click event is working but not the change event - http://jsfiddle.net/qneL65zs/23/

Comment: form change doesnt work with backbone - answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350211/backbone-js-html-select-radio-change-event-is-not-firing-but-click-event-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

After JSfiddle was added, we determined that only the "change" on the form element events were not firing (click was working) - further search reveals that this is an issue with backbone:

[Backbone.js html select / radio change event is not firing, but click event is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350211/backbone-js-html-select-radio-change-event-is-not-firing-but-click-event-is)

Comment: Got rid of the `this.model.bind` statements and still no change.

Comment: when is it rendering?  you may want to add the event listeners after render, for example this.on('change, '#QuoteAge')

Comment: Made the change to the `el`, nice catch. I'm still be seeing any of the events fire though. Is there a way for me to check the view and see if it's methods are attached to an events (i.e. a `console.log(this)` statment in `initialize`)?

Comment: Yes, you originally posted a screenshot, and it was showing the MODEL.  please console.log the VIEW.

Comment: Just added to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try calling `render()` after you initialize the view?

i.e

```
   var quoteHistory = new QuoteHistory;
   var quoteView = new QuoteView({ model: quoteHistory });
   quoteView.render();
```

Comment: The dom events are delegated, so how would this help?

Comment: Gave it a shot but no luck. Events still don't fire.